# divide all columns by each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like 1 and I am trying to create a new data frame 2 which consists of ratios of each column of above data frame.

[image: Initial DataFrame]

[image: Intended Output DataFrame]

I tried below mentioned logic.

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference([col])].div(df[col], axis=0)\
                    .add_suffix('/R') for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output is:

```
    B/R     C/R     D/R     A/R     C/R     D/R     A/R     B/R     D/R     A/R     B/R    C/R
0   0.46    1.16    0.78    2.16    2.50    1.69    0.86    0.40    0.68    1.28    0.59    1.48
1   1.05    1.25    1.64    0.95    1.19    1.55    0.80    0.84    1.30    0.61    0.64    0.77
2   1.56    2.78    2.78    0.64    1.79    1.79    0.36    0.56    1.00    0.36    0.56    1.00
3   0.54    2.23    0.35    1.86    4.14    0.64    0.45    0.24    0.16    2.89    1.56    6.44
```

However, here I am facing two issues. One is I am getting both A/B and B/A which are not needed and also increases number of columns. Is there a way to get the output only A/B and eliminate/restrict B/A.

Second issue is with Naming of columns using add suffix method which does not convey which is divided by which. Is there a way to create column names like A/B for Column A divided by column B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `combinations` with divide columns in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,8],
})

from  itertools import combinations

L = {f'{a}/{b}': df[a].div(df[b]) for a, b in combinations(df.columns, 2)}

df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df)
    A/B       A/C       A/D       B/C       B/D       C/D
0  1.25  0.714286  5.000000  0.571429  4.000000  7.000000
1  0.60  0.375000  1.000000  0.625000  1.666667  2.666667
2  1.50  0.666667  1.200000  0.444444  0.800000  1.800000
3  1.80  2.250000  1.285714  1.250000  0.714286  0.571429
4  0.40  1.000000  2.000000  2.500000  5.000000  2.000000
5  1.00  1.333333  0.500000  1.333333  0.500000  0.375000
```